# Adding push notification functionality to an existing app

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

Hey,
Is it possible to add push notification functionality to an already existing app?
Will it be possible if I have to change the appID?

I am asking this because I am about ready to submit my app, and currently don't require push notifications. In the provisioning portal I have already created default appID, with a wildcard Bundle Identifier.

I will however need the push notification service in the future - And for that I will need to use a non-wildcard Bundle Identifier. Will it be possible to easily change in the future? I prefer not to go through the push notification service certification right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the bundle id of your app (inside the info.plist and iTunesConnect). So choose your bundle id now currectly for later usage.

You can sign you app with other certificates (without wildcard) on an update.